# How to get OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET for linkden in python?

Tags: python, post, get, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have obtained OAUTH_TOKEN by following procedure.

```
import linkedin
from linkedin import linkedin
import oauth2 as oauth
import urlparse
import simplejson
import codecs  


API_KEY = "my key"
API_SECRET = "my secret"
RETURN_URL = "https://www.my.com"
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

print authentication.authorization_url  # open this url on your browser
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

authentication.authorization_code = 'my temporary code'
outh_code =authentication.get_access_token()

OAUTH_TOKEN = outh_code[0]
```

Sucessfully I got OAUTH_TOKEN but when I am using oauth.token() function, It requests both OAUTH_TOKEN and OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET as its aurguments.

How do i get OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET. I can't find any formation about this. Can anyone please help.

Also If I don't require a token secret, how to use this token secret to fetch basic profile information of any person?